# At what resolution can the 5D Mark 2 record at least over a minute of ML RAW video at 24 fps?

Tags: magic-lantern, raw

Adding to this, assuming all of this is being done on a 32GB 120MB/S SandDisk card, how many minutes would it take before the entire card is filled up?

Comment: You'd get way more input from a ML forum. Try http://www.magiclantern.fm/forum/index.php?board=49.0 for lots of chat about RAW.